# Magento admin dashboard 404 error after trying to login

Tags: magento-1.7, admin, 404-page

My Magento (1.7.0.2) is installed in a `subfolder`. It was all working fine until couple of days back after hacked. The `htaccess` files are now being sorted correctly. The `home page`, `categories` & `product` pages are working fine (they were throwing me 404 errors`.

Now, still having issues with `Admin Dashboard` when I enter login details - it shows me **"Whoops, our bad..."** error.

The URL shows `domainname.com/index.php/admin/index/index/key/62f8f/`

I've removed `index.php` from all URLs, still it shows up here!

What could be missing, which is not letting me login to admin dashboard?

TIA

Answer (score 1):

Finally after hours of exploring, I've managed to fix an issue by hard-coding Admin URL generation in `/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/store.php` by overriding the `_updatePathUseRewrites` method.

Find this snipped in above mentioned file

```
protected function _updatePathUseRewrites($url)
    {
        if ($this->isAdmin()
            || !$this->getConfig(self::XML_PATH_USE_REWRITES)
            || !Mage::isInstalled()
        ) {
            if ($this->_isCustomEntryPoint()) {
                $indexFileName = 'index.php';
            } else {
                $indexFileName = basename($_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']);
            }
            $url .= $indexFileName . '/';
        }
        return $url;
```

And make the following change   `$url .= '/';` to ensure there is no `index.php` prefix.

Also wrote a whole post regarding all 404 issues I faced after the hack. If you're in similar situation & need to save tons of hours - hope this article helps. http://techzoom.org/fixing-magento-404-error-whoops-on-all-pages-admin-dashboard-after-login/

(Moderators, please remove the link if you think it's inappropriate)